# Expression Expected error while constructing a custom sql query in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The following is an expression written for a data set. Multiple values are not allowed in parameter `@prmLogicalFeedType` . The type of this parameter is text. This parameter is passed to expression as it is.

[image]

```
="select * from  dwh.StagingReadyPublishDetail where LogicalFeedType = '" & @prmLogicalFeedType & "'"
```

An Error message is displayed as followed while running.

```
The CommandText expression for the query ‘dsMainPublishReport’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected.
```

I have to construct a much bigger query by making use of concatenation which includes multi valued parameters. I cannot move forward as even the straight forward query using expression has failed.

### Adding my detailed requirement

I have a parameter called `@prmSalesOrgRegion` which is multi valued and text.
The values will be concatenated with , and supplied to the expression
[image]

[image]

```
=JOIN(Parameters!prmSalesOrgRegion.Value,",")
```

couple of examples for my requirement

**Example 1**

```
@prmLogicalFeedtype = Rebates
@prmSalesOrgRegion = APJ,AMS
```

in this case I want a query like below

```
select * from dwh.StagingReadyPublishDetail where LogicalFeedType = 'Rebates' AND
salesOrgRegion in ('APJ','AMS')
```

**Example 2**

```
@prmLogicalFeedtype = Rebates
@prmSalesOrgRegion = APJ,AMS,(NULL)
```

in this case I want a query like below

```
select * from dwh.StagingReadyPublishDetail where LogicalFeedType = 'Rebates' AND
(salesOrgRegion in ('APJ','AMS') OR salesOrgRegion is null)
```

**Example 3**

```
@prmLogicalFeedtype = Rebates
@prmSalesOrgRegion = (NULL)
```

in this case I want a query like below

```
select * from dwh.StagingReadyPublishDetail where LogicalFeedType = 'Rebates' AND
salesOrgRegion is null
```

This is the query which I am expecting to work for the above examples but it is giving error (expression expected)

```
="select * from  dwh.StagingReadyPublishDetail where LogicalFeedType = '" & @prmLogicalFeedtype & "' AND " 
& 
IIF(@prmSalesOrgRegion="(NULL)","SalesOrgRegion IS NULL  ","") 
& 
IIF(Instr(@prmSalesOrgRegion,"(NULL)")>0 AND Len(@prmSalesOrgRegion)>6, " (SalesOrgRegion in('" & Replace(Replace(@prmSalesOrgRegion,"(NULL),",""),",","','") & "') OR SalesOrgRegion is NULL)  ","") 
& 
IIF(Instr(@prmSalesOrgRegion,"(NULL)")<=0 AND Len(@prmSalesOrgRegion)>0," SalesOrgRegion in('" & Replace(@prmSalesOrgRegion,",","','") & "')  ","")
```

Comment: If you want to add a parameter to your DataSet your code should be `LogicalFeedType == @prmLogicalFeedType`  for single values parameters and `LogicalFeedType IN (@prmLogicalFeedType)` for multi values parameters, what i didn't understand thought, why do you put your query in an expression

Comment: I just added detailed requirement in the question

Comment: In that case, i would change my query to bypass null values: `ISNULL(LogicalFeedType, 'NoValue') IN (prmLogicalFeedtype ) AND
ISNULL(salesOrgRegion, 'NoValue') IN (@prmSalesOrgRegion )`.
And no join on `prmSalesOrgRegion`. make sure to change in the availables values `null` to `NoValue`

Comment: I just added the custom query which was constructed to the end of the question. I know your method is simple but is it possible to create the query like I did.

Comment: I would start by just outputting the individual parts of the expression to textboxes so you can see what is being generated. It's might just be something simple like a missing `'` etc.  For the first part, I would probably use '="'" & JOIN(Parameters!prmSalesOrgRegion.Value,"','")' & "'"` as this should give you the correct string with all the apostrophes in place. This should make the final expression simpler.